# Symfony - NelmioApiDocBundle: Show parameter description imported from class

Tags: php, rest, documentation, symfony, nelmioapidocbundle

I am using the [**NelmioApiDocBundle**](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle) together with the PHP framework **Symfony3** for a **REST API**.
I want to display the description of my parameters in the /api/doc page.
Is this possible without adding the parameters manually?
I want to import it from the input/output class.

This is how my documentation looks:

[image: Screenshot]

Here ist my **@ApiDoc** of the controller action (/api/user/login) which generates the documentation:

```
 * @ApiDoc(
 *     section = "user",
 *     resource = true,
 *     description = "Checks the user credentials and returns an authentication & refresh token if they are correct",
 *     input = { "class" = "AppBundle\Libraries\Core\User\LoginRequest", "name" = "" },
 *     output = { "class" = "AppBundle\Libraries\Core\User\LoginResponse", "name" = "" },
 *      statusCodes = {
 *          200 = "Returned when successful",
 *          400 = "Returned when request syntax is incorrect",
 *          404 = "Returned when the page is not found",
 *          429 = "Returned when the client sent too many requests during a time period",
 *          500 = "Returned when an internal server error occured",
 *          501 = "Returned when an unavailable request method is user (GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, ...)",
 *          503 = "Returned when the service is unavailable at the moment eg. due to maintenance or overload"
 *      },
 *
 * )
```

AppBundle\Libraries\Core\User\LoginRequest **class**:

```
class LoginRequest implements JsonSerializable
{
    /**
     * The username.
     *
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Type("string")
     */
    public $username;

    /**
     * The password.
     *
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Type("string")
     */
    public $password;

    /**
     * Defines whether or not to save the refresh token as cooke.
     *
     * @var bool
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Type("bool")
     */
    public $rememberPassword;

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function getRememberPassword()
    {
        return $this->rememberPassword;
    }

    public function setRememberPassword($rememberPassword)
    {
        $this->rememberPassword = $rememberPassword;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return [
                'username' => $this->username,
                'password' => $this->password,
                'rememberPassword' => $this->rememberPassword
        ];
    }
}
```

I would like to use the desciptions of this class, eg. for username: "The username.", for password: "The password." and for rememberPassword: "Defines whether or not to save the refresh token as cooke.".

Thanks for the help.

Greetings
Orlando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only few places where NelmioApiDoc extracts the data for the later generated view. But one thing you can do is to add your descriptions to the form-type of your entity/model class.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('rememberPassword', CheckboxType::class, array(
        'label' => 'input.remember.password',
        // description will be passed to table in ApiDoc view
        'description' => 'Defines whether or not to save the refresh token as cookie',
    ));
}
```

I know that you wanted to know if there are ways to put more informations to the documentation automatically, but there are only few. But if you want to add additional informations you can do it through comments, like in the example below.

```
/**
 * Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
 *
 * #### Example of expected response ####
 *     [
 *         {
 *             "username": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
 *             "password": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
 *             "rememberPassword": {
 *                 "1": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
 *                 "2": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
 *                 "3": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
 *             },
 *         },
 *         ...
 *     ]
 *
 * @ApiDoc(
 *     section = "user",
 *     resource = true,
 *     description = "Checks the user credentials and returns an authentication & refresh token if they are correct",
 *     input = { "class" = "AppBundle\Libraries\Core\User\LoginRequest", "name" = "" },
 *     output = { "class" = "AppBundle\Libraries\Core\User\LoginResponse", "name" = "" },
 *      statusCodes = {
 *          200 = "Returned when successful",
 *          400 = "Returned when request syntax is incorrect",
 *          404 = "Returned when the page is not found",
 *          429 = "Returned when the client sent too many requests during a time period",
 *          500 = "Returned when an internal server error occured",
 *          501 = "Returned when an unavailable request method is user (GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, ...)",
 *          503 = "Returned when the service is unavailable at the moment eg. due to maintenance or overload"
 *      },
 *
 * )
 *
 */
public function getLoginRequestAction()
{
// your code
}
```